# VBA to copy data into another Tab based on Value

Tags: vba, excel

I need help developing a code to copy data from weekly computation onto Data Tab based on the number being greater than Zero.You can find the link of the file here.
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=16887893812603084209.

Your help will be greatly appreciated thanks. I am very new to VBA so dont have much idea.

Comment: welcome to SO! unfortunately this question will probably get down-voted, ignored or both as you need to show us what you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

Put this in Google:

> stackoverflow: move data into another tab [excel-vba]

Once you have tried some code of your own amend your question so we have more specific code to work with